# Cannot access a disposed object in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Having a small issue.

I am receiving a `Cannot access a disposed object` error for `Form1`

Upon clicking a menu item on the main form - the below `Sub` is called, which opens another form `Form1`

```
Private Sub ToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ToolStripMenuItem.Click
    If (Not Form1.Visible) Then
        Form1.Show(Me)
    End If
End Sub
```

Within `Form1`, there is a `Try` block. If it isn't passed, `Form1` should show a message box, before closing down. The message appears, but it's then that I receive the error (where it says `Form1.Show(Me)`)

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Try
            'DO STUFF
        Catch
            MsgBox("Error loading in data. Please contact an administrator")
            Me.Close()
            Return
        End Try

End Sub
```

I am quite new to this type of programming, and struggling to fix the problem even after searching similar problems. Could someone please assist or point me in the right direction?

EDIT: So looks like this is due to trying to close the form during the `Load` event. So my question now is, are there any simple alternatives? I've found ways of doing this in `C#`, but not a lot for `vb.net`

Comment: Don't be closing a form in its `Load` event handler.

Comment: Do you know how I should be doing it? The form has a combo box which is populated in the `Load` event handler. If this process fails, I just need to close the form, or stop it form opening altogether.

Comment: If the operation fails, set a flag. Read that flag in the `Shown` event handler, display the message and then close the form. If you're determined that the form not show at all if the database operation fails then do the database operation outside the form. You could create a class that tries to get the data and only displays the form if it succeeds, passing it the data into the form.

Comment: You can cheat by using `Me.BeginInvoke(Sub() Me.Close())`, but the better option is to not put the "showing" logic in the form.  Figure out the logic beforehand whether or not to load the form, save some cpu cycles.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option:

```vb
Private loadFailed As Boolean = False

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        '...
    Catch ex As Exception
        loadFailed = True
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    If loadFailed Then
        MessageBox.Show("Load failed")
        Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

In that case, the form will show with the message over it, then it will close when the message is dismissed. Here's an option that will not display the form:

```vb
Friend Module Form1Manager

    Public Sub ShowForm1(owner As Form)
        If Not Form1.Visible Then
            Try
                '...

                'Pass data to Form1 here.

                Form1.Show(owner)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("Load failed")
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub

End Module
```

and, to use that:

```vb
Private Sub ToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Form1Manager.ShowForm1(Me)
End Sub
```